# Looking for a good date range picker. Any suggestions?

Tags: javascript

We're building a dashboard similar to what Google Analytics has done and want a date range picker similar to theirs.  Is anyone aware of an off the shelf javascript utility that can do this?  I suppose we could roll our own if needed, but would love to find something ready to go.  Below is an image of what Google's looks like.

[image]

Comment: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_interactive_date_range_picker_with_shortcuts might do the trick, or at least set you down the right path.

Comment: What is this screenshot from? I would be interested in seeing the timeline view

Comment: Also this might be useful: https://codecanyon.net/item/caleran-date-range-picker/19454049

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this [jQuery plugin](http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/) which allows you select date range. See the last two examples on the page.

[alt text http://img510.imageshack.us/img510/4323/picture9ux.png](http://img510.imageshack.us/img510/4323/picture9ux.png)

[alt text http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/8297/picture8x.png](http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/8297/picture8x.png)

Comment: Updated version https://github.com/foxrunsoftware/DatePicker/

Answer (score 1):

Yui calendar should do.
here's an example of how to deal with date intervals http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/calendar/intervalcal.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [Jquery UI datepicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker).

Comment: This doesn't allow you select a range.

Comment: It can be converted to [select a date range](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2013/01/jquery-ui-datepicker-examples.html#example-7).

Answer (score 0):

jQueryUI datepicker is cool.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#multiple-calendars

You can modify it for ranges instead of dates.

Comment: It does ranges: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range